# How to List the containers in azure blob storage?

Tags: azure, containers

I am developing a social network application.

I want to creat ,in azure storage, a container for each user (client) joining a social network, which means user1 has a container named container 1, and inside container 1 there will be user 1 profile in xml format and a profile picture of user 1.

Similarly, for user2 there will be container 2 created in azure blob storage and then user 2 profile is saved in xml format and profile picture of user 2, and it goes like this so for, let say, 10 users there will be 10 containers.

If i want to list all 9 users' information stored in Azure storage in different 9 containers from user client 1, how could i do that?

I am using webservice, but the challenge I am facing is how to collect all the 9 user profile information located in 9 different containers.

Answer (score 43):

The following should do the trick -

```
            CloudStorageAccount account =
            CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DataConnectionString");
        // We need to access blobs now, so create a CloudBlobClient
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        IEnumerable<CloudBlobContainer> containers = blobClient.ListContainers();
```

Answer (score 12):

**For newer versions of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage**, use the right variant of `CloudBlobClient.ListContainersSegmentedAsync` method. Example usage is as follows:

```
private static async Task<IEnumerable<CloudBlobContainer>> ListContainersAsync(CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient)
{
    BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
    var containers = new List<CloudBlobContainer>();

    do
    {
        ContainerResultSegment response = await cloudBlobClient.ListContainersSegmentedAsync(continuationToken);
        continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
        containers.AddRange(response.Results);

    } while (continuationToken != null);

    return containers;
}
```

Usage of the above method will be as follows:

```
string connectionString = "<your connection string>";
CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(connectionString, out CloudStorageAccount storageAccount);

if (storageAccount == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connection string did not work");
}

CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var containers = await ListContainersAsync(cloudBlobClient);
```

Alternately, you can create an extension method as follows:

```
public static class CloudBlobClientExtension
{
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<CloudBlobContainer>> ListContainersAsync(this CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient)
    {
        BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
        var containers = new List<CloudBlobContainer>();

        do
        {
            ContainerResultSegment response = await cloudBlobClient.ListContainersSegmentedAsync(continuationToken);
            continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
            containers.AddRange(response.Results);

        } while (continuationToken != null);

        return containers;
    }
}
```

Usage of the above extension method will be as follows:

```
string connectionString = "<your connection string>";
CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(connectionString, out CloudStorageAccount storageAccount);

if (storageAccount == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connection string did not work");
}

CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
IEnumerable<CloudBlobContainer> containers = await cloudBlobClient.ListContainersAsync();
```

For more details, please refer to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.listcontainerssegmentedasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlobClient_ListContainersSegmentedAsync_System_String_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobContinuationToken_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) and [Balkan's Blog](https://ahmet.im/blog/azure-listblobssegmentedasync-listcontainerssegmentedasync-how-to/)

**For older Azure Storage versions**, use `CloudBlobClient.ListContainers` method. Example usage is as follows:

```
string connectionString = "<your connection string>";
CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(connectionString, out CloudStorageAccount storageAccount);

if (storageAccount == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connection string did not work");
}

CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var containers = cloudBlobClient.ListContainers();
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Azure Blob Storage client library v12 for .NET

```cs
using Azure;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(azStorageConnString);
var containerList = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainers();

foreach (var container in containerList)
  // doImportantWork
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CloudStorageAccount account =
    CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DataConnectionString");

// We need to access blobs now, so create a CloudBlobClient
var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

IEnumerable<CloudBlobContainer> containers = blobClient.ListContainers();

// This will return you list of containers
var containerList = containers.Select(e => e.Name).Tolist();
```

Comment: Please edit that answer and explain what you are doing in detail, and make sure to put spaces in front of lines that are code.  Review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and read how to format your edits.