# Get all blob Uris from Azure container and sub-directories

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

How can I get a list of all of the blob Uris from the entire azure blob storage container in C#?

Comment: I asked and answered because there was no answer to this already on this site.

Comment: There are, in fact, several questions (and related answers) to this, on the site.

Comment: None that do this exactly. Some are very specific. This does one thing. Gets all the Uris in the container and searches the entire folder/name structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated, Thanks you David Makogon for pointing me to the "useFlatBlobListing:true" flag.
I have updated this answer and I am aware it may be flagged as a duplicate. 
This will return all blob Uris in the container.

```
 public List<string> GetAllBlobUrisInContainer(string containerName, string blobNamePrefix = "")
    {
        List<string> uriList = new List<string>();
        var container = GetBlobContainer(containerName);
        var blobList = container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);
        foreach (var cloudBlockBlob in blobList)
        {
            uriList.Add(cloudBlockBlob.Uri.ToString());
        }

        return uriList;
    }
```

Comment: Your solution is recursively looking at directories in a container. But... you should know that there are only two levels to the hierarchy: container, and object. There are no subdirectories, and no need to search recursively. Anything that looks like a subdirectory is in the name alone: just names with directory slashes.

Comment: Thank you David. I know that. This solution will return all the blob uris in the container regardless of name structure.

Comment: Right - what I'm saying, though, is that you can get the same results without doing any of that. You need to specify a flat blob listing. Such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43945874/272109) describes.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is redundant actually. There is no need to list directories in a blob container at first, since there are only two levels in Azure Blob Storage: containers and blobs, directory is just a virtual concept which doesn't really exist in the service side.

Below is the simplified code:

```
public List<string> GetBlobUris(string containerName, string blobNamePrefix = "")
{
    List<string> uriList = new List<string>();
    var container = GetBlobContainer(containerName);
    List<CloudBlockBlob> cloudBlockBlobs = GetBlobs(containerName, blobNamePrefix);
    foreach (var cloudBlockBlob in cloudBlockBlobs)
    {
        uriList.Add(cloudBlockBlob.Uri.ToString());
    }

    return uriList;
}

public List<CloudBlockBlob> GetBlobs(string containerName, string blobNamePrefix = "")
{
    var container = GetBlobContainer(containerName);
    return container.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Where(b => b.Name.StartsWith(blobNamePrefix)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that will return all the Uris in the container. One has to actively insert the directory path which is what my code is designed to prevent.

Comment: Please forget about **directory** since there isn't such a layer in Azure Blob Storage service at all. I was using `blobNamePrefix` instead in code above to prevent confusion.

Comment: Zhaoxing, I tested your answer and I see you failed to understand what my code did. Obviously its easier to get the first layer like this example. This will return all the blobs at the base directory, or without slashes in the name. My code will identify all the virtual directories and return all the Uris of all the blobs. Sorry Zhaoxing, this answer is redundant.